# Loading data avoiding the entities found in the persistence context

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, persistence

I'd like to execute a method (compareEntities ) which requires the entity which is currently in the database and the object which has just been saved. Something like this in my DAO where em is the EntityManager:

```
public void save(MyObj myObj) {
    MyObj previous = null;
    MyObj current = null;
    Integer id = myObj.getId();     
    if (id == null) {
        // new
        current = em.persist(myObj);
    } else {
        previous = em.find(MyObj.class, id);
        // update
        current = em.merge(myObj);
    }
    compareEntities (previous, current);
}
```

The problem is that, as the entity which is going to be saved comes from the database and I have made some changes on it, when I try to get the data from the database (with the find method) I get the data with the changes because the entity is found in the persistence context. Is there any way to get the data which is in the database without the changes I have done to the entity inside the same transaction?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it would be better to move the whole logic to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reliable way to find the unchanged entity using a persistence context that has a modified instance of the same entity currently attached. The persistence provider might have flushed the changes to the database, in which case a subsequent `SELECT` will show the *changed* object, because that's what's current in the transaction. Even if the persistence provider hasn't yet flushed the changes it is *required by the specification* to return the *same instance* from a `find` call for the same key. It isn't allowed to return an "unchanged" object.

You will need to use another connection to fetch the data from a new transaction. How to do that depends on your programming model. In a JTA programming model with container-managed transactions like EJB3 you'd use a `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` annotated business method. In plain JPA you'd get a new EntityManager and `find` the object by ID.

I suspect you're trying to implement an audit log system, in which case you should look at [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers), the PostgreSQL [audit trigger example](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus), or standard JPA Entity Listeners, all of which offer much better ways to achieve this task. Try explaining the underlying problem you're trying to solve, the "why" for this question's "how".